# What happens when you make a hard link to a file in /mnt, and then unmount?

Tags: mount, filesystem, hard-link

As far as I know, hard links will not break when a file is deleted. Because the file will remain to exist.

But what happens when you `mount` a file system to `/mnt` for example, create a hard link to a file on that volume, `unmount` the volume, and then try to open the hard link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot create hardlinks across mount boundaries.  You'll get something like:

```
ln: failed to create hard link ‘X’ => ‘Y’: Invalid cross-device link
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, hard links will not break when a file is deleted. Because the file will remain to exist.

But a hard link to a file on a different file system is not possible, in a fundamental way.

Practically, that means you can not create hard links to files on different file systems, and get an error when trying.

Now, why is it not possible?

A hard link is what you normally call a file. When there is a file system mounted in `/mnt`, and you see `/mnt/example.txt`, you see the name of the hard link `example.txt` on the  file system in `/mnt`, that points to the data of thee file.
A file system contains file data and file names to access parts of the data. There is a reference from the name to the data. This reference is a hard link.

Creating a hard link means to create a reference to the same file data with a new name.

So a hard link is a central part of a file system, referencing the data. That means that a hard link to a different file system is not possible - because it is a different file system.

In principle, there could be a file system that spans more than one partition, and enlarges when adding `/mnt` to it. Then a hard link to a different partition, but in the same file system could be created, and would break when the partition with the data is unmounted.

With this reasons, it's not only that a hard link to a different file system can not be created, but that it can not even exist by definition.**strong text**